# Get contents of HTML file and add to PHP String

Tags: html, php

I've got an HTML file I use as a template for a PHP email, and I want to just pull the contents of the HTML file and put it in a string, but my PHP content isn't showing.

My current html file can be seen at http://pastebin.com/iNgaHRky

I can get the file to be pulled, but the PHP parts in it aren't running. The email is just coming through as if I was previewing the file itself.

My Code:

```
ob_start();
include(site_url()."/emails/templates/new_user_admin.html");
$adminMessage = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean();
```

Can anyone let me know if what I'm trying to do is possible, and any way to get this to work?

I've also tried `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Why not just rename it to a `.php` and use include like the rest of us?

Comment: @Fluffeh because it's just a template file that I want to be able to preview when coding without needing a server environment. :).

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo No errors at all. The email comes through, just showing all the PHP tags though.

Comment: Not to be offensive, but it really boggles me that you can code on a "non-server environment". Surely you have a test machine set up to see how things work? how do you do thorough testing if you aren't seeing how it REALLY works?

Comment: could be that you need text/html in the email header, not sure exactly how but you can search

Comment: @Fluffeh Oh I wouldn't dream of coding outside of a server environment! I have tons of test machines set up. But this is part of a script I'm developing for others to use and I don't know what they have in that area. :). These files are templates that just get pasted into the PHP script, and I was hoping to try cut that step out.

Comment: @andrew already set :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just interprets the file as a pure string.

I really dont think you should be expecting the php parts to be working. they will just be text now. not php.

You could try using string replace on the string created once you have used file_get_contents() http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

So, for example, you would put in the html file {{siteurl}} and use string replace to replace it with something like .site_url()."/emails/images/generic-header.jpg